# Elements crashed after updating vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a project maked with Laravel + vuejs and vuetify, everything is fine from the beginning, but after updating vuetify for using some new elements, i found that many elements are crashed because either is deprecated or changed.
I have to change my code too, but as the project gets big, it becomes difficult.
The question : what is the right solution based on your experiences with vuetify?

thank you in advance

Comment: Which components are broken? What about them is specifically broken? Would you mind sharing some code via jsfiddle.net or something like it? You may want to try to revert to an older version, in the meantime.

Comment: I followed the release notes to know what exactly changed here [release notes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases)